# With ReLU activation, are we adding if conditions to a neural network's toolset?

Tags: machine-learning, activation-function

I was reading [Reverse Engineering a Neural Network's Clever Solution to Binary Addition](https://cprimozic.net/blog/reverse-engineering-a-small-neural-network/). Without repeating the whole article, it seems the network figured out addition was already a part of its toolset (maybe the addition in x*W **+** B?), so instead of coming up with an logic gate-based adder like a human might it "cheated".

For some reason, I immediately thought of ReLU activation when reading this. We know that ReLU and its cousins (SwiGLU, ELU, GELU) work better in practice than sigmoid/tanh. The vanishing gradient problem in sigmoid/tanh is often said to be reason and I'm *mostly* satisfied with that answer, but it's still not completely intuitive to me why ReLU works better.

**Is it right to think of ReLU as adding conditional statements to the network's toolset?** With ReLU, the network can do boolean operations. For example, it's easy to come up with weights such that C = ReLU(Linear(A, B)) will reliably activate iff A and B both activate. We've effectively given the network the tools to build an AND gate when it needs one. Whereas with sigmoid/tanh something like this would be difficult due to the overall smoothness.

I know this is a bit handwavy, but I find it much easier to work with ideas when they "fit" in my head perfectly, so I'd love to get a intuitive explanation for ReLU superiority.